# can't upgrade jenkins for java version error

Tags: java, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I have Jenkins running on my Ubuntu 14.04, and i am trying to do upgrade for jenkins using normal `apt-get install jenkins`, but when i try to do it, i keep getting the error:

```
Setting up jenkins (2.73) ...
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)

Aborting
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Nothing shown in the jenkins logs, even when restarting jenkins i get the same jave wrong version error,

Any help please?

Comment: You're using Java 7, but Jenkins needs Java 8 - see: 
 https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/jenkins-has-upgraded-to-java-8/

Comment: That was it, thanks alot :), please post your answer,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using Java 7, but Jenkins needs Java 8 - see: https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/jenkins-has-upgraded-to-java-8

Answer (score 4):

You need JDK 8 to run jenkins:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Update your java version by using these commands,

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa 

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

and follow this command to change your default selection mode of java version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It should be set to java 8 values.