# Can't Install Jenkins even though I have JAVA 8

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

*Ubuntut 14.04 LTS*

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591869/cant-upgrade-jenkins-for-java-version-error) I need JAVA 8 and so I downloaded both the JDK and JRE. Unfortunately when attempting to install jenkins again

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

I still get the error message

```
Aborting
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_2.176.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Found an incorrect Java version
Java version found:
java version "1.7.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.17) (7u211-2.6.17-0ubuntu0.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.201-b00, mixed mode)
```

Checking my $PATH and it shows the following

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_221/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

The java that should be used is 8.
Even running

```
java -version
```

Gives me what I expect

```
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

**Why do I get the java version error if I have JAVA 8 installed? What more do I have to do to ensure that JAVA 8 is the default?**

I was unsuccessful in trying

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

and got

```
Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jre
```

Side note, when attempting to run eclipse from the side bar I get an error about the JAVA version as well. Running eclipse from command line works fine though.

Does it have to with default-java symbolic link in my /usr/lib/jvm folder? It points to the Java 7 openjdk... Doing ls -la shows the links

```
default-java -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-7-openjdk-amd64
java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: What about `$JAVA_HOME` env variable ?

Comment: I get nothing when i echo $JAVA_HOME... @ArnaudClaudel

Comment: so try setting it and try again.

Comment: Try to set it to the jdk8 home

Comment: The variables you have in your own users are irrelevant. The installer runs under a different user, and indeed it checks the symbolic link definitions. Take a look at the `update-java-alternatives` command.

Comment: I added $JAVA_HOME and set it to the JDK but still same error as before

Comment: I will look into that now @RealSkeptic thanks

Comment: @RealSkeptic the alternatives was the solution, thanks for push in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into update-java-alternatives and update-alternatives, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787757/how-to-use-the-command-update-alternatives-config-java)

I checked the current alternatives for java

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and got

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

Using one of the answers I found, I added the alternative for the java executable doing the following command

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_221/bin/java 1
```

Then I checked again to see that my alternate java was available in the list

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Which now gave me

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.8.0_221/bin/java               1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then I entered 2 and tried to install and it worked. I can even run eclipse now from the side bar instead of having to run it from command line.

I appreciate the point in the right direction RealSkeptic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the below options:

1) Download a Docker based Jenkins image and spin up Jenkins as a container using below command:

```
    - docker pull jenkins
    - docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v volume_name:/var/jenkins_home --name jenkins -d jenkins
```

2) Download jenkins.war file and extract the war file using the below command:

```
    java -jar jenkins.war &
```

Answer (score -1):

If possible, try to run Jenkins in a docker container. It takes care of such issues.